# How can I change the email address associated with the Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, accounts

How can I change the email address associated with the Stack Overflow account?

Comment: Just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/4614773

Comment: @mmking It won't work for _you_ because that link goes to the OPs edit page. Replace the number at the end with your user id to get your link. you can find your user id in the link to your profile- It'll be the number after "user/".

Comment: Generalized link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

Answer (score 2):

Click your profile at in the page header and then click the Edit Profile and Settings tab on your account page. Then scroll down to the Private Information heading and the email field is right there.

Comment: Hm, as of today, the settings appearence has been changed. There is a "My Logins" section, but for the classic login I only can change the password, not the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link [www.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current). Thanks to Zoe